# Are flash cookies from different firefox profiles stored separately?

Tags: firefox, cookies, portable-apps, firefox-profile

Are LSOs from different Firefox profiles stored separately?
or are they stored in one central location?

Are LSOs from firefox portable stored separately?

Answer (score 2):

LSOs are stored in a central location, regardless of profile or browser used. **Attention:** This applies to most browsers with the *exception of Chrome*, if the integrated Flash player is used.

## **Firefox/Opera/IE locations**

**Windows**

```
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\
```

**Mac OS X**

```
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

**Linux/Unix**

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

## **Chrome locations**

**Windows**

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot\#SharedObjects\
```

**Mac OS X**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/
```

If you want Chrome to also use the same storage location, you can download the latest version from Adobe's site and enable/disable the appropriate plugin from the options in Chrome. More information on that subject can be found at [Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html).

Comment: What about firefox portable?
Do they store flash cookies in 1 central location too?

Comment: That I don't know for sure. This is guesswork but I think the portable version uses the same location as the non-portable version does.

Comment: I tested this for you and Firefox portable Flash cookies are stored the same way as on non-portable Firefox (I cleared all old flash cookies, opened FF portable and opened a flash site. And the Flash cookie instantly appear in the two folders mentioned above)

Comment: Nicely compiled information; this allowed me to move flash game settings from Chrome on Windows inside Parallels to my MacOSX host into Firefox's shockwave local storage location, and seemlessly continue with my hard-earned game progress ;).

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Fedora 23.0 system, the LSOs are stored in the directory
  ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/VG6D94TT
and there is a copy in
  ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys

I had to delete both copies manually, since the BetterPrivacy Firefox plugin can't find them at all, even when pointed at the directory in which they reside.