# Will my portable browser leave any mark behind if I use it on my pc at my workplace thru my USB stick?

Tags: safari, opera

And how about if I copied the files out from my USB stick to the PC hard drive, will it all be the same, or is it much better to leave it inside my USB stick whilst using the portable browser?

How about histories, downloads, cookies, caches, etc, etc, will it be all inside the folder where the portable browser is, no mark or any traceable stuffs whatsoever that it will leave behind inside the PC that I used?

Comment: Chances are if it is not a *portable* version of the browser, i.e you just installed it to an external drive, than it will still target local directories. I know Google Chrome has a portable version of their browser that was modified to prevent AppData and local directories to be made and are instead managed on the root drive.

Comment: I just downloaded from portableapps.com, something like that. Then I got the installer, the I run it, then it creates a folder, thats it, I saved it inside my USB stick, then used it at my workplace. I think its portable, coz theres no need to install, just run it from USB stick. My question is, are stuffs like this don't leave any marks behind inside the PC that I had used?

Comment: I use PortableApps as well. In that case I would say in most cases you are safe especially if you are using the PortableApps application on your drive, it will manage your file contents. As with anything though, someone with expertise could probably find some trace of the program somewhere but for all extensive purposes you are good.

Comment: Just a word of warning though, it might not leave any trace on your computer, but that doesn't mean the network administrator can't see what your browsing from this portable install. So depending on your motive, the whilst the answer to your specific question is no, you should be aware that this doesn't make your browsing invisible. As an admin myself, I'd never go looking on individual PCs to obtain browsing history, I'd be hitting proxy server logs on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About Opera Portable: No traces, except Flash cookies

[Opera 12.xx](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/opera_portable) will save all files inside its profile. If you choose *Portable mode*, that folder is places inside your installation folder whereas this folder should be somewhere on your USB stick.

Some examples where Opera stores temporary files (on your USB stick)

```
\Opera\profile\application_cache
\Opera\profile\cache
\Opera\profile\icons
\Opera\profile\jumplist_icon_cache
\Opera\profile\pstorage
\Opera\profile\temporary_downloads
\Opera\profile\temporary_downloads
\Opera\profile\temporary_downloads
\Opera\profile\widgets
\Opera\profile\cookies4.dat
\Opera\profile\download.dat 
\Opera\profile\bookmarks.adr
\Opera\profile\global_history.dat
```

There won't be any traces left if you remove the USB stick.

**But:** In normal cases Adobe Flash Player is installed on the main system and Opera will use this plugin when installed. As soon as you visit a Flash-based website, the Flash plugin will save cookies to:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects
```

and this will leave traces. [Read here](https://superuser.com/questions/605877/are-flash-cookies-from-different-firefox-profiles-stored-separately) fore other browsers and there Flash cookie locations

Comment: So does that mean, for example in Opera, there's only one place where it leaves some marks, and that is: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects, right? On ur given lists above, where in there is my histories? Another thing, will all my bookmars, extensions, add-ons etc., be also inside the installation folder inside my USB stick, right?

Comment: Added those infos: Extensions go to `Widgets` folder, bookmarks to `bookmarks.adr` and history to `global_history.dat`. As I said, all Opera files will be saved inside the profile folder.

Comment: What can u recommend: 1.Use my portable browser directly from my USB stick ..OR.. 2.Copy the installation folder from USB stick to PC, then launch it from there. At the end of the day, move it back again from PC folder to USB stick? Is there a difference? Coz I don't want to have my USB stick worn out, from whole day of using it, want to plug it in the morning, then plug it out in the evening, is there a difference in performance or whatsoever?

Comment: That entirely depends on your USB stick read/write speed. Normal USB 2.0 sticks usually are between 5-25 MB/s where you will notice a slight difference between start up time for any browser on stick vs HDD. After the start there's no difference anymore. I would start the browser from stick.

Comment: Would u mind telling me why, nixda? So u will be using ur stick the whole day, instead of just using it once in the morning, then once in the evening to transfer all the files back.

Comment: Can't give you a precise answer: I guess complete copying of 150 MB (my current Opera portable folder size) two times (morning+evening) is far more than all little cache files over the day together. However, I never heard of a degree in USB stick performance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Probably

The long answer is: It depends on how your Network Administrators have chosen to image your work computers and implement their security infrastructure.  For example, most facilities that I have worked in don't even allow External USB cards to function on work machines specifically because of things like what you are asking.  Users trying to use portable Browsers or Operating Systems can open your network to huge vulnerabilities if the file the user is trying to run is outdated, unpatched or compromised in some way.  Your company may or may not also have native/3rd party event trackers that report when users run .exe's, .mp3's, .zip's, etc. which can do anything from simply logging the event, to sending an message to the IT Department distro-list, to automatically disabling your account due to “potential account compromise”.  It's always funny to see some of the musical tastes that people in my building have when they try and store stuff to our Network Sharedrive. :)

Edit: After reading the comments section, it seems that you are trying to use the portable version of Chrome.  This is harder to decet then if you were simply going to try and install it *from* a USB stick, but there are still ways of detecting this.

Comment: Our company is not so strict, no network monitoring or whatsoever. The only thing that they were doing is to check each PC, like once a week, defragment it, fixed some issues. So, to be sure, where inside the PC do I need to check if my portable browser leave any marks behind? But do u think it reallly leaves some marks behind? Whats the purpose of it being portable?

Comment: To be specific, Im using portables Opera and Safari. I usually run it from my USB stick, although im not sure if there are marks that it left behind my workstation. I just use this 3 days ago. And 3 more days to go, the IT guy would check each PC for defragment and antivirus updates. Im just curious if he could ever find it out, that I used portable browser there.

Comment: It's really hard to say with 100% certainty, since I don't know your work network, but I would imagine that if they aren't blocking External USB Sticks, they probably aren't searching for traces of a portable browser either.

Comment: Last question. How about I do have Chrome there at my workstation PC, the real one, meaning it is really installed there, would there be any conflicts if I used the portable browser of Chrome, coz there will be 2 chromes running, the real one and the portable one. Or it will run separately, all things (bookmarks, saved passwords, cookies, caches, downloads, etc), will the two have their own stuffs, and there will be no conflicts? I have'nt tried it yet, im just using Opera and Safari coz I dont know what will happen if I used protable chrome, because there is already chrome there.

Comment: I've never tried to use two different versions of Chrome at once, but it seems to be that there is some level of support for it. [link 1](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/179235?hl=en) [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window)

Answer (score 0):

It will leave small traces of evidence in Windows registry (but you have to actually know what to look for), even if you just plugin the USB stick and navigate to the folder of the browser on the stick.
Regarldess of whether it's portable Chrome, Firefox, K-Meleon, Opera, Maxthon, or something else.

A bit more if you launch the browser (to a blank page) and exit.