# Can cookies read information from different Firefox profiles?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies, privacy-protection, private-browsing

I've been working now for a couple of years by splitting my web activity in different firefox profiles. I use one only for gmail, another one for general browsing and some others for spotify and web-based whatsapp.

I do this under the assumption that cookies stored on one profile cannot read the information of different profiles.

Am I fooling myself?

I'm working on a linux machine. This option can be done as well in chrome, but I don't trust chrome.

Comment: [This may be relevant](http://superuser.com/questions/605877/are-flash-cookies-from-different-firefox-profiles-stored-separately)

Comment: The [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) suggests that each profile stores its own (http) cookies in a .sqlite

Comment: Thanks. Still I wonder if cookies can read something like `../*/*.sqlite` and boom, info across profiles is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Each Firefox profile exists in its own folder and has its own set of data including cookies, history, passwords and so on.

There is also an addin for Firefox that attempts to simulate Chrome's multi-personality feature. However, I've found it to be rather limited and does not implement separate webdb's for example.

I do use Chrome's capabilities for multiple personalities but I cannot attest to it's security. Certainly it works well for maintaining multiple logins to the same service (e.g. Google and Microsoft Azure).